# How to manually force remove a old service worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

My problem right now is that I have one service worker using old code called `service-worker.js` I have since decided to completely remove that worker and instead switch to a new one called `sw.js`

However while i was implementing `service-worker.js` I had forgot to set my nginx cache to `no-cache` so now I am stuck with a old service worker with a max life cache using outdated code that hasn't been updated even though I have ran deployments with new code everyday. **I have a computer in house that says it has been running on this old service worker for 2 weeks now**

**Am I just stuck with this old service worker forever now?**

I am using `SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin` with the old service worker and `OfflinePlugin` for the new

**here is the old service worker code**

`webpack.config`

```
new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin(
  {
    filename: 'service-worker.js',
    minify: true,
    navigateFallback: PUBLIC_PATH + 'index.html',
    staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/, /(icons)/],
  }
),
```

`src/registerServiceWorker.js`

```
export default function register () { // Register the service worker
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = '/service-worker.js';
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(swUrl)
        .then(registration => {
          registration.onupdatefound = () => {
            const installingWorker = registration.installing;
            installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
              if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
                if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                  // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
                  // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
                  // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
                  // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
                  console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
                } else {
                  // At this point, everything has been precached.
                  // It's the perfect time to display a
                  // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
                  console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
                }
              }
            };
          };
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
        });
    });
  }
}

export function unregister () {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

*Here is the new service worker*

`webpack.prod.js`

```
new OfflinePlugin({
  autoUpdate: true,
  ServiceWorker: {
    events: true
  }
})
```

`index.js`

```
  OfflinePluginRuntime.install({
    onUpdating: () => {
      console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdating');
    },
    onUpdateReady: () => {
      console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdateReady');
      // Tells to new SW to take control immediately
      OfflinePluginRuntime.applyUpdate();
    },
    onUpdated: () => {
      console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdated');
      // Reload the webpage to load into the new version
      window.location.reload();
    },

    onUpdateFailed: () => {
      console.log('SW Event:', 'onUpdateFailed');
    }
  })
```

Comment: Have you tried just typing "nginx reload"? That way it updates the config without downtime which should invalidate the old service worker.

Comment: Yea that's the thing I have 

  location ~* (service-worker\.js)$ {
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    expires off;
    proxy_no_cache 1;
    etag off;
  }

Killed my nginx server and everything

Comment: Is the service worker still registered even if you killed the server? In that case, unregister the service worker in your browser and refresh?

Comment: Is the issue server-side or client-side?  Do you see the old SW in the applications tab in the dev tools?

Comment: Client side, yes I see the old one from about a week ago

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome Dev tools under the Application tab, find the service worker that you want to remove and click on unregister.

[image]